# ¿Qué significa ": m_name{ name }" en C++?

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**: m_name{ name }** no entiendo esta linea esta dentro de una clase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se le llama inicialización de miembros y, como su nombre lo dice, se encarga de inicializar el miembro `m_name` con el valor del parámetro `name`

Otro ejemplo sería:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Persona
{
   private:
        std::string m_nombre;
        std::string m_apellido;

   public:
       Persona(const std::string& nombre, const std::string& apellido) :
          m_nombre(nombre),
          m_apellido(apellido)
       {

       }  
};

int main()
{
    Persona persona("Nombre","Apellido");
    return 0;
}
```

`m_nombre` de `persona` valdrá "Nombre" y `m_apellido` valdrá "Apellido"

Comment: Me estoy enterando ahora de que se puede inicializar usando llaves y no parentesis. Esto es así? Quiero decir, en el caso de la pregunta no sería `Animal(const::string& name):m_name(name){}`

Comment: A partir de C++ 2011 se pueden utilizar llaves.